# Actions on Google Storing Training Phrases localy

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a portal using which I can update my fulfillment. I want to be able to do the same with training phrases, is it possible to store training phrases locally in webhook like fulfillment JSON.

Comment: Can you provide a detailed example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Updated the questions, hope that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to store training phrases on Dialogflow only, the reason is Dialogflow uses these phrases to train its model which will match your input request to an intent.
These phrases are not part of webhook, and cannot be stored locally on some other server.

Comment: There is a [REST API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest) for Dialogflow, where one could build their own training phrase sync mechanism, but it's something that would need to be built on one's own.